# Apply Format on Excel Charts

Tags: excel, charts, formatting

Is there any easy way to apply the format of any particular Excel Chart to other Excel Charts.
Not just for size, but for Title Font, Borders, Font Size, etc.

Not sure if it matters but I'm using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should help you: [Apply Chart Formatting to Other Charts](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/apply-chart-formatting-to-other-charts/)

Comment: Your Google-fu is strong. Thank you.

Comment: @Overseer10 I won't decline that, but Peltier site is in my bookmarks for about 5 years so far)

Answer (score 1):

You can create Custom Chart Types (which will be accessible from the normal "Chart Type" UI.

http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s191/how_to_create_custom_charts_in_microsoft_excel.htm

This is a non-VBA solution; may be more user friendly and distributable than code modules. Downside is that they will still likely require some fine-tuning, but if you're primarily looking at standardizing things like font size, colors, etc., Custom Charts will do the trick.

Comment: That's exactly what was I was looking yesterday. Sad to say that I already updated all my charts.

Comment: Ahhh that's too bad. Well, just keep this in mind for next time. There are definitely options VBA and non-VBA to help speed up the chart formatting :)